# Get mySQL MONTH() to use leading zeros?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

How do I specify to mySQL's MONTH() function to return '08' instead of 8 in this query?

I'd like the sort to work datewise.  Currently getting results for date like

```
2006-9
2007-1
2007-10
2007-11
```

current query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), CONCAT(YEAR(`datetime_added`), '-', MONTH(`datetime_added`)) as date FROM `person` WHERE (email = '' OR email IS NULL) 
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 267, accepted):

Use the following instead:

```
DATE_FORMAT(`datetime_added`,'%Y-%m')
```

---

**Explanation:**

`DATE_FORMAT()` function lets you format the date anyway you like using specifiers described   in the table below (taken verbatim from [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)). So a format string `'%Y-%m'` means: "A full year (4 digits), followed by a dash (`-`), followed by a two-digit month number".

Note that you can specify the language used for day/month names by setting [`lc_time_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lc_time_names) system variable. Extremely useful. Refer to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for more details.

| Specifier | Description |
| --- | --- |
| %a | Abbreviated weekday name (Sun..Sat) |
| %b | Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec) |
| %c | Month, numeric (0..12) |
| %D | Day of the month with English suffix (0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, …) |
| %d | Day of the month, numeric (00..31) |
| %e | Day of the month, numeric (0..31) |
| %f | Microseconds (000000..999999) |
| %H | Hour (00..23) |
| %h | Hour (01..12) |
| %I | Hour (01..12) |
| %i | Minutes, numeric (00..59) |
| %j | Day of year (001..366) |
| %k | Hour (0..23) |
| %l | Hour (1..12) |
| %M | Month name (January..December) |
| %m | Month, numeric (00..12) |
| %p | AM or PM |
| %r | Time, 12-hour (hh:mm:ss followed by AM or PM) |
| %S | Seconds (00..59) |
| %s | Seconds (00..59) |
| %T | Time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss) |
| %U | Week (00..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 0 |
| %u | Week (00..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 1 |
| %V | Week (01..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 2; used with %X |
| %v | Week (01..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 3; used with %x |
| %W | Weekday name (Sunday..Saturday) |
| %w | Day of the week (0=Sunday..6=Saturday) |
| %X | Year for the week where Sunday is the first day of the week, numeric, four digits; used with %V |
| %x | Year for the week, where Monday is the first day of the week, numeric, four digits; used with %v |
| %Y | Year, numeric, four digits |
| %y | Year, numeric (two digits) |
| %% | A literal % character |
| %x | x, for any “x” not listed above |

Comment: While not what he asked, this seems to answer what he should have asked.

Comment: Why can day of month be 0?

Comment: Because 0000-00-00 is a valid date (depending on settings)

Comment: @SOFe
> Ranges for the month and day specifiers begin with zero due to the fact that MySQL permits the storing of incomplete dates such as '2014-00-00'.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: yes, but the author asked for how to let MONTH() return month number with leading zero and didn't asked how to use date format.

Comment: I agree there is a difference between answering a question and solving the actual problem. The answer to question as stated is pretty much 'compile your own version of MySQL which returns a zero padded string from MONTH()`. That's hardly useful.

Answer (score 43):

You can use padding like

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*), 
    CONCAT(YEAR(`datetime_added`), '-', LPAD(MONTH(`datetime_added`), 2, '0')) as date 
FROM `person` 
WHERE (email = '' OR email IS NULL) 
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: Met the need in hive. DATE_FORMAT() function is not supported in hive. Your answer helps.

Answer (score 7):

MONTH() returns an integer, so of course there's no leading zero.  You will need to convert it to a string, left-pad the '0' and take the last 2 characters.

Answer (score 6):

```
DATE_FORMAT(`datetime_added`,'%Y - %m')
```

Comment: I believe without spaces: `'%Y-%m'`

Answer (score 1):

Using the **LPAD** function also works

```
LPAD(MONTH(your_date_column_here),2,'0')
```

See example below using current date

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's what Dani's answer was in 2011.