# MySQL MONTH not prefixing 0?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date-format

When I am querying with MONTH(DATE) return `1` if date is in january,I want to return `01` instead of `1`,

ie,Prefixing `0` for common standard.

`January` - `01`

`February` - `02`

`March` - `03`

etc, How it is possible in MySQL?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/7043794/779320

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes `month()` will give you the month number, for prefixing 0 you may use `date_format` function.

```
mysql> select date_format(curdate(),'%m');
+-----------------------------+
| date_format(curdate(),'%m') |
+-----------------------------+
| 05                          |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: @ShihabudheenMuhammed, you can mark this as answer if this satisfies your question.