# MySQL - How to convert date to the month has leading zeros?

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to insert dates into a table and the date is in this format:

`8/3/2021`

However I want to add a leading 0 before the month and day so the date shows `08/03/2021`. Also I want to add it as a string concatenated with another string so `test123-08/03/2021`

Comment: Dates don't have a format, only dates formatted as *strings* - which you should do when presenting your dates, not storing your dates; for all we know that could be August 3rd

Comment: @Stu `I want to add a leading 0 before the month` ... so we know the date is March 8th in this case.

Comment: Hopefully though that's for presentation purposes only and not a single source of truth.

Comment: the following solutions mentioned in the below stackoverflow post helps in retrieving the month with leading zeroes from mysql - the  other standard function would be to_char for date to string conversion -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043794/get-mysql-month-to-use-leading-zeros - what has been tried and what failed, would help in getting better solution, suggestion from the awesome developer communities.

Answer (score 1):

You should be inserting your source dates into a proper date or datetime column. Then, to *view* your dates in the format you want, use the `DATE_FORMAT()` function with the appropriate format mask:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%d/%m/%Y') AS date_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really store date in that format then you may try this:

```
SELECT 
       DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_col_string,'%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y') as 'zero-padded',
       CONCAT(string_val,'-',DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_col_string,'%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y')) as 'concatenated'
FROM mytable;
```

Use `STR_TO_DATE()` function to change the *date* value to standard MySQL date format of `YYYY-MM-DD` then use `DATE_FORMAT()` function to display the date value as per your desired output. The second operation is adding `CONCAT()` function on the converted date with your selected string. I'm assuming that your date value is `d/m/y`, because as @Stu mentioned in the comment, since you're not storing as MySQL standard date format, that means `8/3/2021` can be either `d/m/y` or `m/d/y`. With a standard date format value, the query would be shorter:

```
SELECT 
       DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'%d/%m/%Y') as 'zero-padded',
       CONCAT(string_val,'-',DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'%d/%m/%Y')) as 'concatenated'
FROM mytable;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d6b037071597199b06e8f2f6a3388b4)